# Unable to make POST request on axios (React-Native)

Tags: android, react-native, networking, axios

I am making a POST request to "Cloudinary" server to upload an image and sending formdata using axios in react-native. The whole process is working fine on iOS but on android i am getting "Network Error".

I am using axios 0.18.0 and stuck on this from last 3 days. Someone please help me.

This issue has been faced by many people but there is no solution so far.

```
 var photo = {
  uri: image.sourceURL,
  type: image.mime,
  name: image.filename,
 };

 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('file',photo); 
 formData.append('upload_preset','abcde');

 axios({
   url:'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/abcde/upload',
   method:'POST',
   headers:{
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },
   data:formData
 }).then(function(response){

 }).catch((error) =>{
  //Network error comes in
 });
```

The exact console error is:

```
Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:567)
at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:397)
at XMLHttpRequest.js:503
at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:179)
at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:351)
at MessageQueue.js:116
at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (MessageQueue.js:314)
```

Can someone point me in right direction as i am stuck here from last3 days. 
P.S: Same code works fine on iOS.

Comment: having same issue, from what was able to discovered after some time spent is that  in react native for some reason body stay empty when posting form data see opened bug in Axios - [link](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1321). and behind the scenes Axios will remove `Content-Type` header if body is empty

Answer (score 1):

I also struggling on this issue for quit while. But I figured out the issue of my axios post network createError on Android device now. The reason to axios Network Error is because the form data I passed to axios contains wrong type of data object I guess. I have include an image object(ImagePicker object from Expo) as a one of param of form data which not accept by axios I think. Axios might only receive string, float, int or image as param. image cannot pass as param, it is not an type of image, it is an react native object, I have removed it and include an image field as param by assign image.uri to value of param then it works. Hope this will help some of people who may encounter same problem as I was facing before. 
  Deleting some of your form data one by one when you are testing axios Network error, you will find out which one is the cause of issue.

Answer (score 0):

first of all to get correct error message. console error.response and in headers add

`Accept: "application/json",
content-type: "multipart/form-data",`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `type: 'image/jpeg'` to your FormData

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', {
      uri: imageURL,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      name: 'image-name'
})
```